# Python web-scraping: problem with soup.select

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm developing a python script to scrape data from a specific site: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AUDUSD%3DX/history?p=AUDUSD%3DX

I'm using BeautifulSoup. The interesting data on this page are :
[image]

I'm using soup.select method this time, the class name is **W(100%) M(0)** and my code is as below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AUDUSD%3DX/history?p=AUDUSD%3DX"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
table = soup.select(table:has(-soup-contains("W(100%) M(0)")))
print(table)
```

And this does not generate the result I want.

I have also tried this way:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AUDUSD%3DX/history?p=AUDUSD%3DX"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
table = soup.select("W(100%) M(0)")
print(table)
```

And there is error as shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryanngan/PycharmProjects/Webscraping/seek.py", line 8, in <module>
    table = soup.select("W(100%) M(0)")
  File "/Users/ryanngan/PycharmProjects/Webscraping/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1973, in select
    results = soupsieve.select(selector, self, namespaces, limit, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ryanngan/PycharmProjects/Webscraping/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soupsieve/__init__.py", line 144, in select
    return compile(select, namespaces, flags, **kwargs).select(tag, limit)
  File "/Users/ryanngan/PycharmProjects/Webscraping/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soupsieve/__init__.py", line 67, in compile
    return cp._cached_css_compile(pattern, ns, cs, flags)
  File "/Users/ryanngan/PycharmProjects/Webscraping/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 218, in _cached_css_compile
    CSSParser(
  File "/Users/ryanngan/PycharmProjects/Webscraping/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 1159, in process_selectors
    return self.parse_selectors(self.selector_iter(self.pattern), index, flags)
  File "/Users/ryanngan/PycharmProjects/Webscraping/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 985, in parse_selectors
    key, m = next(iselector)
  File "/Users/ryanngan/PycharmProjects/Webscraping/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 1152, in selector_iter
    raise SelectorSyntaxError(msg, self.pattern, index)
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Invalid character '(' position 1
  line 1:
W(100%) M(0)
```

How can I scrape the above data using the soup.select method? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try this selector `table[data-test='historical-prices']` to locate the data from that table of your interest. Btw, don't forget to use a headers while sending requests.

Answer (score 1):

Using direct class selectors (e.g. `.W(100%)`) breaks because it's invalid CSS selector syntax.

However, you can get around this using contains syntax which is expressed through `attribute*=partial`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
}
response = requests.get(
    "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AUDUSD%3DX/history?p=AUDUSD%3DX",
    headers=headers
)
# select any element where class contains "W(100%)" and class contains "M(0)":
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
table = soup.select('[class*="W(100%)"][class*="M(0)"]')
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your method. When I `print (table)`, it generates `[]`. I still cannot scrape the whole table. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @ryantl your code should check whether response you receive is successful. Some URLs in your example return status code 404 with text "Will be right back..." meaning the urls you're scraping are either invalid or your scraper is being blocked. You can check request success via `response.status_code` as in: `response = requests.get(url); print(response.status_code)` if it's not 200 then there are no tables. You are most likely missing some headers in your requests, see my blog on headers in web scraping for more info https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-avoid-web-scraping-blocking-headers/

Comment: @ryantl seems like just adding `user-agent` header might be enough in your case, see my edit.